# How to remove the decimal point from a number

Tags: sql

How to delete decimal point in amount?

If I have:

```
Amount = "100.24"
```

I want convert the value into:

```
"10024"
```

Please help me with simple query.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use the replace function:

```
select replace(Amount,'.', '') from tableName
```